# White space while scrolling in real mobile. Background is provided in body

Tags: html, css

Everything looks fine while scrolling and inspecting in the laptop's browser. When opened in a mobile browser, and scrolled, the top address bar hides automatically. It results in a white blank space at the browser's end.

**File Structure**

```
|--assests
   |--bg-img.png
|--index.html
|--styles.css
```

index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>bg-css-help</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

styles.css file:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("./assests/bg-img.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

**What I did:**

- I changed the min-height of body tag from `vh` to `svh` and `lvh`. It doesn't help.
- I tried to make a new div and put the same background with `width:100%` and `width:100vh`. That doesn't help either.

You can visit the [online link](https://tajpuriya27.github.io/bg-css-help/) here and inspect in your mobile.

I used chromium 119.0 version for checking.

Comment: I have visited the link you've provided and it seems to work fine on both desktop and mobile phone. Can you tell the resolution the issue occurs on?

Comment: I recommend you to check in landscape mood of mobile. I used Samsung J7 Prime for checking.
When you scroll - the top address bar hides and you will notice whitespace at the end of the website.

Comment: First, by "mobile" what do you mean? Android with Chrome? Or iOS Safari?

Comment: I checked in Samsung(Android 8.0) with Chromium version 119.0(Chrome and Brave both).